# Rails Admin global label change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

There is a label tag to change the label of an attribute, but it has to be mentioned for every tab. For ex. If I have an attribute abc but I want the label as ABC (not Abc that happens automatically), but I want all other labels to remain as they are, I am having to go and edit each block like SHOW, LIST, EDIT etc individually and set a label for that attribute in all those options after which I will also have to include defaults.

Is there any way to do it globally, like to set label of an attribute globally in a model based configuration so that I don't have to do it individually and it reflects in all the tabs.

Note : I am configuring rails admin in every model using rails_admin block

Comment: If you are using simple_form it is quite easy to do this by using translations, you just edit your config/locales/en.yml. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n

Comment: any idea without simple form ? Rails admin is doing the magic by itself.